# Calling functions in C-like syntax

Tags: objective-c, iphone, syntax

How can I write code in Xcode max similar to syntax in Java or C++ in particular call functions (messages), static or dynamic? I just want to simply call Objective-C function in C-like syntax.

How to when I write `NSString * s = NSString.alloc().init();` 
(or similar, for example, `NSString::alloc().init()`, or `NSString::alloc.init` or `(new NSString()).alloc().init() ;))` 
in Xcode (or another iPhone  dev environment), the compiler did not cause an error and it will run.

or code like

```
NSString * a = NSString.alloc().init(); //or similar 

bool b = a.compare("abcdef"); //or bool b = a->compare("abcdef");
```

will run.

?

Comment: This question does not make sense without further explanation of **why you want that**.

Comment: Objective-C doesn't work that way. You *can* get and directly execute method implementations but you'd have to do it each time you use it since the runtime can change. If you don't like the objective-c syntax, I suggest programming in another language. The Xamarin/Mono stuff is pretty good if you want to do iOS development and C# calls methods the way you prefer.

Comment: i just be used to java or c syntax and want see this syntax

Comment: Welcome to Objective-C. It has some new syntax you have to learn. Enjoy your stay.

Comment: to Jason Coco: thanks

Comment: Consider this - your question is similar to asking "I want to speak Chinese but I want to use only English grammar because I am used to it. How do I do that?"

Comment: Not clear what you're asking or why you want to do that.  It's a different language, it uses a different syntax.

Comment: I think the question is valid given the fact that Objective-C _does_ have an exception (dot notation for method without arguments, as in `object.method`) which is used a lot with properties. If you see stuff like `self.view.frame.size.width` you can get the impression that Objective-C does support a second way of calling methods (and the example I've just given is the reason why I avoid the dot notation; which parts are method calls, which are structure access?).

Comment: @DarkDust But you just gave an example that is actually much cleaner looking and easier to understand with the dot syntax. Also, as you pointed out, only part of it could actually be written without it, since part of it is a struct. You could write it as `[[self view] frame].size.width`, which looks much worse and is harder to read. Also it's more confusing to somebody. Once somebody learns the language, it's *really* not that hard to get used to using both normal and dot syntax.

Comment: @DarkDust Every programmer has his/her own likes and dislikes. I prefer dot notation but I never use array subscripting with `[]` and I never use storyboards (I use lots of xibs though).

Comment: @Gavin: A structure access is _very_ cheap. But a method calls is expensive and sometimes can be _very_ expensive! For example, if you access the `view` property of a controller for the first time, there's a lot of loading. I've seen way too often people repeat the same stuff like `self.view.frame` several times in a method, without realizing that's two method calls each. Method calls and structure access are two very different concepts and I think it's a mistake to have the same syntax for them. You have to _know_ which part is a method call and which is not. That is confusing to newbies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to call Objective-C methods in a different syntax, with one exception:

You can call methods that do not take arguments with a dot notation as in `object.method` (this is mostly used with properties, which in turn are getter and setter methods that are generated by the compiler).

So the way methods are called in Objective-C (`[object method]` or `[object methodWithArgumentA:someValue argumentB:otherValue]`) cannot be changed. This is the syntax chosen by the language designers. And once you've worked with it a little, you'll understand why:

Method names in Objective-C tend to be very descriptive and are used as if Objective-C had named arguments (technically, that's not the case). Like:

```
[someData writeToFile:aFileName atomically:YES];
```

How would you transfer this to a dot notation? It might look like this:

```
someData.writeToFileAtomically(aFileName, YES);
```

Now, if I see a method just `writeToFileAtomically` I wouldn't be surprised if it just would take one argument (whether to atomically write to file; but which file?) or no argument (just write to a file atomically; again, which file?). With the Objective-C notation the intention is more clear.

And now consider `object.addObserverForKeyPathOptionsContext(o, k, op, c)` vs. `[object addObserver:o forKeypath:k options:op context:c]`.

Whether one likes this syntax or not is subjective. You don't seem to like it, as you wouldn't have asked how to get rid of it. But if you want to write Objective-C code you'll have to accept that this is the way it's done and you cannot change it. Embrace it, I found it weird at first as well (also coming from a long C++ and Java background) but now I miss the very verbose way of calling methods with arguments of Objective-C when working in other languages.

Answer (score 4):

Objective-C has C functions. In fact, all valid C code is valid Objective-C code. So yes, you can call functions with C syntax.

However, objects and message sends use Objective-C's syntactic extensions to C, which are not configurable. They are part of the language. You can't change Objective-C's syntax any more than you could make C++ use Smalltalk syntax.

Comment: thanks, i know this way. I can call functions like CGRect() or similar. But not alloc and init ) or you said objective c functions.  To write c-like code i tried to write wrapper class in objective c++, but for it i need to create a lot of code ).